# Install package from without adding PPA

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, ppa

Is there a way to install a package via a simple URL without having to add a PPA beforehand? Something like `apt-get https://url.to.package.deb`? Or perhaps some command line options that would add the PPA, update, and install the package all at once? Seems like I've seen other package managers that do this. I just find it a hassle to type the commands to add a whole repository just so I can install only one of its packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the `.deb` file link, then download that deb file by,

```
wget https://url.to.package.deb
```

If you want to download a package then run,

```
apt-get download <package-name>
```

It will download all the .deb files related to the package.Finally install all the `.deb` files by running,

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that a PPA, or any other `apt` repository, is not just about *installing* packages. It's also about automatically *updating* them. And the hassle of manually checking for updates, download and upgrade packages yourself is *far* worse than just adding a repository.

Compare the 2 workflows:

**Adding a repository and installing from it:**

- Add the PPA repository. What you call "hassle" is for now is a single command: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:user/repo`
- Install the package: `sudo apt install package`

**Doing all yourself:**

- Visit the software website and *find the correct version* for your platform (32 or 64 bits? PC, Mac or Raspberry? Ubuntu 18.04 or 22.04?)
- Download the `.deb`: `wget https://xxx.com/yyy.deb`
- Install the package: `sudo dpkg -i yyy.deb`
- Some time later (2 months? 1 week?), visit the software website again to see if there are any updates
- If so, do most of above steps again

Repositories save you from *all* this trouble.

Comment: I can see how it would be less trouble in the long run to add the PPA within the design constraints of how apt works. However, I wonder why the package itself doesn't just include meta data about where it can be updated so that as a user I don't have to maintain this manually.

Comment: @Adam: _some_ packages do contain code to add their repository when the package is installed, such as from Oracle, Microsoft and Google. But many consider this a security risk and a poor practice.

Comment: And what would be the benefits of such metadata? You'd still have to go to the developer website (possibly having to find out _who_ and _where_ it is), then select the appropriate version for your platform, then download and then install. That's a lot of hassle even if needed only once per package.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, Not really. By using something like

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<goalppa/ppa>
```

you are telling your system that you want the (file/program/code) you download from this ppa to be supported from this location and get updates from there.

Its a security question for sure, allowing new ppa's that is.
But the security concerns for just getting the (file/program/code) may be greater in the long run if it develops a security problem down the line.
Also easier to get super delicious updates (Mmmmmm updates).