# Install content from a PPA in terminal without giving permission to update?

Tags: software-installation, ppa

If you have a PPA link, but you don't want add it as a repository, is it possible to install a program via the link but not have it ever update? Essentially using the PPA as a source for one time download rather than adding it as a trusted entity for updates?

I'm seeing [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/446776/135947) but what if I had something like this `ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp` where you can't run wget? Would it still be possible without searching google to find the appropriate web address?

Comment: What about just downloading and installing the .deb package you want from the PPA's Launchpad site?

Comment: You can add the ppa, install the program, and then remove the ppa.  IMHO, it's a silly way of doing things, but it seems like what you want.

Comment: @mikewhatever it's silly in that you're wasting by downloading extra? I feel like opening the website is too much work if I can just run a few commands from bash.

Comment: Mikewhatever thought it was silly because it appears you're doing something that actually defeats the purpose of what you are doing... installing a ppa to have the latest updates, but removing the ppa to stop the updates (which often involve security patches and bug fixes).

Comment: @L.D.James in the case of gimp that would be true because it's already a default ubuntu package but that's not the case with a lot of PPAs.

Comment: I respect your opinion to have more respect for the merit of `Gimp`'s updates.  But I have that same type of respectful consideration for all the`ppa`'s or `repository` sources I add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off automatic updates from the GUI with:

(click) the `Gear` icon at the top right corner of the screen -> `System Settings` -> `Software Updates` -> (click tab) `Software` -> (select) `Never` (for automatically check for updates). ->

You can also click on the `Other Software` tab and toggle any of your `ppa`'s on or off by placing or removing check marks.

When you decide you want an update from one of them, just place the check mark back.